# An Unexpected Error while trying to delete data

Tags: python, django

I am doing CRUD using serializers and foreign key as tasked,the problem is that when I am trying to delete a data,an error which is completely unexpected has come.
[image]

this error should not be coming as I am not missing the id in the below functions and html code

**NOTE : I am doing soft delete hence the parameter 'isactive' is there**

delete function

```
def delete(request,id):
    deleteclothes = Products.objects.all(id=id)
    delclothes = {}
    delclothes['isactive']=False
    form = POLLSerializer(deleteclothes,data=delclothes)
    if form.is_valid():
        print("error of form when valid:",form.errors)
        form.save()
        return redirect('polls:show')
    else:
        print("error of form when not valid:",form.errors)
        return redirect('polls:show')
```

html code of product_list

```
<td>
  <a href="/delete/{{result.id}}/" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure you want to delete?')">
   <button class="btn btn-danger">
     Delete
   </button>
  </a>
</td>
```

models

```
class Products(models.Model):
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_categories = models.ForeignKey(SUBCategories,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Colors,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media/',width_field=None,height_field=None,null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    sku_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    product_details = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    isactive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

where am I going wrong in the code?

Comment: Seems to be at `Products.objects.all(id=id)`, what fields did you define in Products class ?

Comment: hi Devyl,I have updated the question where I have inserted the model and its fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `deleteclothes = Products.objects.all(id=id)`, whether you retrieve all `Products` by doing :

```
deleteclothes = Products.objects.all()
```

Or you retrieve the one with the id you want (which is what you need here) with :

```
deleteclothes = Products.objects.get(id=id)
```

Comment: that means I would have to try something like filter function right?

Comment: If you want to get several Products but not all of them, yes, filtering is the way to go